# Unusual substitute without delimiter

Tags: regex, perl

I was unable to decipher what this regex does:

```
$c =~ s^.*/^^g;
```

I don't have access to the input or the output.

Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `^` is used as the delimiter.

We may use any printable character as a regex delimiter.

```
s^.*/^^g;

s/.*\///g;
```

Both regex are same

A non-standard delimiter is mostly used to avoid the need to escape the delimiter character within a regex pattern. For

```
$c = "this is a string with / slash";
```

Now your regex should be

```
$c =~ s/.*\///
          ^^
```

Here you are escaping the slash.

Both regex are same.
We will use whatever regex we want. @simbabque mentioned in comment.

```
 s{foo}{bar}gs # here curly braces are delimiter
 s[some][same] # here square bracket are delimeter.
```

And we will use character also a regex delimiter for our convenient

To avoid escaping we can use other delimiters.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: @JohnDoe also in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators and the subchapter before it. You can use whatever single character you want as a delimiter for quote-like operators. If it's a kind of bracket that comes in pairs, those work. `s{foo}{bar}`, `s<foo><bar>` and so on. But `s~foo~bar~` or `s]foo]bar]` also work. You can even use letters. `$foo =~ s sfoosbars;`, but you need a space after the `s`.

Comment: @mkHun: I think you could give a much better example than the answer that you link to. A colon `:` is just as bad as a circumflex `^` and looks like line noise, which is made worse by your attempts to golf the solution and put no spaces after `;` and around `=~`.

Answer (score 6):

The default delimiter for `s///` is the slash, but you can use any printable character as an alternative.

So

```
$c =~ s^.*/^^g
```

is equivalent to

```
$c =~ s/.*\///g
```

Note that using the conventional delimiter requires the slash within the pattern itself to be escaped

Some options are better than others, and in the case where you're just trying to avoid escaping slashes within the pattern I think a pipe character `|` is better

I wouldn't hope to learn too much from this programmer. As you have experienced, `^` is a poor and confusing choice. Also, the `/g` modifier is superfluous, and `$c` is a terrible choice for an identifier

I would write

```
$c =~ s|.*/||
```

Comment: It might be my personal preference, but the pipe doesn't feel like a good fit to me. It looks too much like an or operator. If in doubt with these quote like operators I always use a pair of brackets as the delimiter. Usually the curly ones. After all they enclose two blocks of something. Just not the normal BLOCK block.

Comment: @simbabque: Of course it's personal preference, but you should be writing for other readers. `s|.*/||` is visibly far cleaner than `s{.*/}{}` and has the advantage that both `/` and `|` are simple lines. Yes `s\.*/\\\` will also work, but that's a different problem!